# Where are graphics card drivers on a Mac Pro?

Tags: mac, graphics-card, display-driver

Mac Pro 4,1 with El Capitan

I installed the 7.5.30 driver that NVIDIA said I need for the Quadro 4000. I'm waiting for that card to be delivered but the 7.5.30 driver works with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 1024 MB as well as the 4000.

I found 5 drivers in /Library>Frameworks that are not supposed to work with a 4,1. They were the only drivers there and I have no idea why they were there. I trashed those. Now there are no drivers in the Frameworks folder.

My question is Where is the 7.5.30 driver that I installed? Where are they stored?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the information on the driver version? That doesn't look like any NVidia driver code I've seen.

NVidia only do one combo driver set for Mac, no matter which card you have. You need to choose precisely by your OS build number*. There is a comprehensive list with links at [MacVidCards](http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html)

> Nvidia GPUs receive driver updates soon after each version update of OS X. Only one driver is released by Nvidia and it includes support for all of their modern GPUs. You will not find individually named Nvidia drivers for OS X, they are all titled "Quadro & Geforce Mac OS X Driver Release xxx.xx.xxxxx".

This 'rule' only applies up to macOS 10.13.6 after which they ceased to provide new drivers. Apple's own built-in drivers will still work but may not have the same optimisations.

BTW, you're not supposed to manually shuffle drivers around on macOS. The Mac itself is perfectly capable of doing that for you. All you need to do is install the NVidia web driver. Leave the existing Apple drivers in place. There is a switch inside the web driver control panel to enable switching between the two driver sets. Moving things around manually is likely to break that.

*You can find your precise system build number from the
**** menu > About this Mac > System Report… > Software

[image]